# Add calculated field inside Pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a calculated field to a `Pandas` pivot table like you would in excel. I plan on adding `totals` to my `pivot table` so I would like the calculation to happen inside the `pd.pivot_table()`. My data looks something like this:

```
df = {'name' : ['AAA','BBB','CCC','AAA'],
      'product' : ['X','Y','Z','W'],
      'Jan-2016' : [50,55,80,150],
      'Feb - 2016' :[35,55,10,100],
      'Jan-2017' : [25,27,40,20],
      'Feb - 2017' : [55,25,40,65]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Jan-2016','Feb-2016','Jan-2017','Feb-2017','YTD YOY - Jan'],index=['name', 'product'])

              Feb-2016  Feb-2017  Jan-2016  Jan-2017
name product                                        
AAA  W             100        65       150        20
     X              35        55        50        25
BBB  Y              55        25        55        27
CCC  Z              10        40        80        40
```

I would like to add a calculated field to the pivot table so it will look like this:

```
              Feb-2016  Feb-2017  Jan-2016  Jan-2017  YTD YOY - Jan
name product                                                       
AAA  W           100.0     65.00    150.00      20.0      -0.866667
     X            35.0     55.00     50.00      25.0      -0.500000
BBB  Y            55.0     25.00     55.00      27.0      -0.509091
CCC  Z            10.0     40.00     80.00      40.0      -0.500000
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to solve a complicated problem, please provide an example that your current code doesn't work. Because for the data you provided, your code works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, it "works" but I would like a way to calculate the field inside the pivot, as in an `aggfunc`. I will be adding subtotals for `names` and a `YOY YTD` calculation will give an `inf` result.

Comment: Avoid asking [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Providing a minimal but close to your real problems example would be helpful.

Comment: @Psidom, the `df` I added is as close as I can get to my real problem. I know how to create the `pivot` and I found a solution but my problem is that is not the right solution for my problem. Per (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676) my X is that I can't add a calculated column to the `pivot`. I already know how to do Y which is to add the calculated field to the starting `df`. Perhaps I'm not understanding the XY problem.

Comment: According to your description, it seems that you have duplicated names, otherwise, there is no point for `aggfunc`, is that true?

Comment: Correct! I now understand your previous comment! I'm gonna make a better example.

Comment: @Psidom I just edited the whole question. I hope it's better and I didn't make it any more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated Solution

You still don't need a pivot table from what I understand.

First set your index and then stack and take `pct_change` and then `unstack` and filter for only the 2017 columns with `filter`. Finally, concatenate them together.

```
df1 = df.set_index(['name', 'product'])
df2 = df1.stack().pct_change().unstack(-1).filter(like='2017')
df2.columns = 'YTD YOY - ' + df2.columns.str.slice(0,3)
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

               Feb - 2016  Feb - 2017  Jan-2016  Jan-2017  YTD YOY - Feb  \
name product                                                              
AAA  W               100          65       150        20      -0.350000   
     X                35          55        50        25       0.571429   
BBB  Y                55          25        55        27      -0.545455   
CCC  Z                10          40        80        40       3.000000   

              YTD YOY - Jan  
name product                 
AAA  W            -0.866667  
     X            -0.500000  
BBB  Y            -0.509091  
CCC  Z            -0.500000
```

#### Original Solution

You don't need a pivot table for your calculations. You can simply set the index and then invoke the `pct_change` method.

```
df = df.set_index('names')
df['YTD YOY'] = df.pct_change(axis=1).dropna(axis=1)


       Jan-2016  Jan-2017   YTD YOY
names                              
AAA          50        25 -0.500000
BBB          55        27 -0.509091
CCC          80        40 -0.500000
```

Comment: I edited the question to better reflect my data. Sorry about the confusion. Essentially, I would like to calculate the `pct_change` inside the pivot table so I can calculate the `YTD YOY` for groups.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: What's the advantage of using this solution as opposed to adding a column based on the calculation?

Comment: You can certainly just add each column manually but this solution gives you a way to calculate all 12 month YOY calculations automatically.